# Recursive template consuming node-set and using preceding-sibling axis

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, node-set

I have some XML like this:

```
<TEI>
  <text>
    <div type="scene" n="1">
      <sp xml:id="sp1">
        <speaker>Julius</speaker>
        <l>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</l>
        <ptr cRef="..." />
        <stage>Aside</stage>
        <ptr cRef="..." />
        <l>consectetur adipisicing elit</l>
        <stage>To Antony</stage>
        <l>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
      </sp>
      <sp xml:id="sp2">
        ...
```

And I need to lift all the `<stage>` elements up one level to become siblings of the `<sp>`s, breaking the `<sp>`s up so that the `<stage>` elements retain their preceding and following relations with the other elements inside the `<sp>`, e.g.

```
<TEI>
  <text>
    <div type="scene" n="1"> 
     <sp by="#Julius">
       <l>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</l>
       <ptr cRef="..." />
     </sp>
     <stage>Aside</stage>
     <sp by="#Julius">
       <ptr cRef="..." />
       <l>consectetur adipisicing elit</l>
     </sp>
     <stage>To Antony</stage>
     <sp by="#Julius">
       <l>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
     </sp>
```

I've been working on an XSLT to do this. It includes a recursive template which is intended to consume all the child elements of an `<sp>` up to (but not including) the first `<stage>` child and emit them in the result tree as children of a new `<sp>`. Then emit the first `<stage>` element. And then recurse on all the elements following that first `<stage>` element. Eventually, when the list of child elements has no `<stage>`s left, all the remaining elements are emitted in the result tree inside a new `<sp>`. Here's the code, including debugging `<xsl:message>`s:

```
<xsl:template name="sp-with-stage">
  <!-- call with speaker -->
  <xsl:param name="speaker" />
  <!-- call with an <sp> element -->
  <xsl:param name="sp" />
  <!-- $content parameter is optional, by default it's the children of the given $sp; this is the parameter whose value is different with each recursive call -->
  <xsl:param name="content" select="$sp/*" />
  <!-- find the first <stage> element amongst the $content node set -->
  <xsl:variable name="stage" select="$content/following-sibling::stage[1]" />

  <xsl:message>ID = <xsl:value-of select="$sp/@xml:id" /></xsl:message>
  <xsl:message>speaker = "<xsl:value-of select="$speaker" />"</xsl:message>
  <xsl:message>content length = <xsl:value-of select="count($content)" /></xsl:message>
  <xsl:if test="$stage">
  <xsl:message>nodes before $stage = <xsl:value-of select="count($stage/preceding-sibling::*)" /></xsl:message>
  <xsl:message>nodes after $stage = <xsl:value-of select="count($stage/following-sibling::*)" /></xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="$stage">
    <sp by="#{$speaker}">
      <!-- process all the nodes in the $content node set before the current <stage> -->
      <xsl:message>Processing <xsl:value-of select="count($stage/preceding-sibling::*)" /> nodes before "<xsl:value-of select="$stage/text()" />"</xsl:message>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$stage/preceding-sibling::*" />
    </sp>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$stage" />
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$stage/following-sibling::stage">
      <!-- if there's another <stage> element in the $content node set then call this template recursively -->
      <xsl:message>Call recursively with <xsl:value-of select="count($stage/following-sibling::*)" /> following nodes</xsl:message>
      <xsl:call-template name="sp-with-stage">
        <xsl:with-param name="speaker"><xsl:value-of select="$speaker" /></xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="sp" select="$sp" />
        <!-- the $content node set for this call is all the nodes after the current <stage> -->
        <xsl:with-param name="content" select="$stage/following-sibling::*" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$stage/following-sibling::*">
      <!-- if there's no <stage> element in the $content node set, but there are still some elements, emit them in an <sp> element -->
      <sp by="#{$speaker}">
        <xsl:message>Processing <xsl:value-of select="count($stage/following-sibling::*)" /> trailing nodes</xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$stage/following-sibling::*" />
      </sp>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This template is then called like this:

```
<xsl:template match="sp[stage]">
  <xsl:call-template name="sp-with-stage">
    <xsl:param name="speaker"><xsl:value-of select="speaker" /></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="sp" select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is with my use of `$stage/preceding-sibling::*` by which I mean to process just the nodes from the current `$content` node set that precede the current `$stage` node. What actually happens is that, in every recursive call, *all* of the nodes which preceded the current `$stage` node from its original `<sp>` context are selected by this `$stage/preceding-sibling::*`. This is despite the fact that the recursive calls get the correct new `$content` node set each time and that the `$stage` node is being taken from that correct `$content` node set.

To clarify, in the case of the above example XML, when the `<stage>To Antony</stage>` is the `$stage` node and the `$content` node contains just:

```
<l>consectetur adipisicing elit</l>
<stage>To Antony</stage>
<l>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
```

the `$stage/preceding-sibling::*` expression still yields *all* the children of the original `<sp>` up to `<stage>To Antony</stage>`.

I guess there must be something about `preceding-sibling` that I'm not properly understanding. Any suggestions? Or even any suggestions of completely different ways to achieve the transformation?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? The structure you have is already less than ideal; the result you show will make it *very* difficult to determine who the current speaker is. Anyway, seeing more of the XML source would be helpful.

Comment: You really need to say whether you want an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution. They are likely to be quite different.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I realise the required output doesn't seem very nice, but I'm working against someone else's schema which is immutable.

Comment: @MichaelKay Sorry, yes, it's XSLT 1.0 as my application is using libxslt

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've updated the example XML, both source and required output. Note that the source `<sp>`s may contain more than just `<l>` elements, including any number of elements. Also note that each result `<sp>` should include *all* the elements between the `<stage>`s.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Also note that I forgot to make explicit in the text of the question that each result `<sp>` will bear a `@by` attribute containing the name of the speaker; this currently works in my transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a grouping problem - you want to group together all the elements inside each `sp` (except `speaker` and `stage`) by their closest preceding `stage` (if there is one).  The standard approach to this in XSLT 1.0 is called *Muenchian grouping*.  You define a *key* giving the grouping criteria and then use a `generate-id` trick to process the *first* node in each group as a proxy for the group as a whole.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <!-- group first by the parent sp and then by the nearest preceding stage.
       generate-id(emptynodeset) is the empty string by definition, so this
       is still well defined for the elements before the first stage in an sp -->
  <xsl:key name="groupKey" match="sp/*[not(self::speaker | self::stage)]" use="
     concat(generate-id(..), '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::stage[1]))" />

  <!-- identity template - copy everything as-is unless overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sp">
    <!-- for each group -->
    <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groupKey',
          concat(generate-id(..), '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::stage[1]))
        )[1])]">
      <!-- the "stage" if there is one - if we are before the first stage in this
           sp then the preceding-sibling:: will select nothing -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::stage[1]" />
      <sp by="#{../speaker}">
        <!-- the following elements up to the next stage -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupKey',
          concat(generate-id(..), '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::stage[1]))
        )" />
      </sp>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works on your example input but may need some alterations if there are any instances where you have two consecutive `stage` elements with nothing else in between them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Have a look at the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sp">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="speaker"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="l[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="stage | l[position() > 1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="l">
    <sp>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </sp>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following example input:

```
<root>
    <sp id="sp1">
      <speaker>Julius</speaker>
      <l>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</l>
      <stage>Aside</stage>
      <l>consectetur adipisicing elit</l>
      <stage>To Antony</stage>
      <l>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
    </sp>
    <sp id="sp2">
      <speaker>Antony</speaker>
      <l>Nullam at dui.</l>
      <stage>Front</stage>
      <l>Nunc lobortis. </l>
    </sp>
</root>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <sp>
      <speaker>Julius</speaker>
      <l>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</l>
   </sp>
   <stage>Aside</stage>
   <sp>
      <l>consectetur adipisicing elit</l>
   </sp>
   <stage>To Antony</stage>
   <sp>
      <l>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</l>
   </sp>
   <sp>
      <speaker>Antony</speaker>
      <l>Nullam at dui.</l>
   </sp>
   <stage>Front</stage>
   <sp>
      <l>Nunc lobortis. </l>
   </sp>
</root>
```

Comment: This solution seems to assume that each `<l>` is transformed into exactly one `<sp>`. Unfortunately, that's not what I need. I've tried to make the example clearer; it's more like arbitrary elements divided by `<stage>`s.